# WPF Datagrid row flashing when clicking on the checkbox

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I'm working on a WPF project and I have a custom datagrid. The problem is whenever I click on the checkbox, the whole row got flashed (like in the image). It just flashed for 1 sec and returned back to the normal white background. Is there a way to disable it?

[image]

XAML code:

```
<DataGrid
        ItemsSource="{Binding PracticeCheckList}"
        Width="270"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        CanUserAddRows="False"
        HeadersVisibility="None"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Background="Transparent"
        GridLinesVisibility="None"
        IsReadOnly="True"
        SelectionUnit="CellOrRowHeader"
        PreviewMouseDown="DataGrid_Popup_PreviewMouseDown">
    <DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRowHeader">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>

    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,6"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>

    <DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,6" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.CellStyle>

    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Item">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>

            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="24,0" Background="Transparent">
                        <CheckBox                                                                        
                                Command="{Binding DataContext.CheckUncheckCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                                Content=""
                                IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                        <TextBlock
                                 Margin="8,2,0,0"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                    Foreground="#84878C"
                                    Text="{Binding Name}"
                                    TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                    </StackPanel>

                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

The flashing or highlighting of the entire row when clicking on a checkbox in your custom DataGrid is likely due to the default row selection behavior of the DataGrid. When you click on an element within a row, such as a checkbox, the row often becomes selected, which results in the highlighting effect you're seeing.

Try this:

To disable this behavior and prevent the row from being highlighted when you click on a checkbox, you can modify your DataGrid's XAML by setting the IsRowSelected property to False for the specific row that contains the checkbox. You can do this using a style trigger. Here's an example of how you can achieve this:

```
<DataGrid ...>
<!-- Your existing DataGrid settings -->

<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,6"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <!-- Disable row selection for rows with a CheckBox -->
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="False"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>

<!-- Your other DataGrid settings -->
```

Comment: thanks Sev for the suggestion, but it still flashing :(

Answer (score 0):

I gave it some more attempts and found a way to disable the highlight for the checkbox cells. Here's the code that works for me

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Transparent" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}" />
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
```